# Retrieving all users from Firebase RealtimeDatabase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I am learning to implement Firebase Realtime Database for an Android app.  In one of the fragments, I am trying to retrieve all the uses in a table.  The "users" node gets automatically generated when someone registers. For registration, I am using FirebaseAuth.

Each user is created post registration. I have 4 users in my users table:

```
1. TestUser1
2. TestUser2
3. TestUser3
4. TestUser4
```

Each user has name, email, mobile,onlineStatus and photo.  I am using the following code:

```
Query query = dbReference.orderByChild(NodeNames.NAME);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                findFriendsModelList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String userId = ds.getKey();
                    if (userId.equals(currentUser.getUid()))
                        return;
                    if (ds.child(NodeNames.NAME).getValue()!=null) {
                        String fullName = ds.child(NodeNames.NAME).getValue().toString();
                        String photoName = ds.child(NodeNames.PHOTO).getValue().toString();

                        findFriendsModelList.add(new FindFriendsModel(fullName,photoName,userId,false));
                        findFriendsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        tvFindFriends.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    }


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), getContext().getString(R.string.failed_to_fetch_friends,error.getMessage()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

When Android fetches the data from table the data is incrementally for each user in the sequence how the username is created.

For example:

I registered TestUser1 as the first user, followed by testuser2, TestUser3 and TestUser4.

When I login in as TestUser1, I get visibility to TestUser2,TestUser3 and TestUser4

```
Login as TestUser1 --> can see --> All other users
Login as TestUser2 --> can see only --TestUser3 & TestUser4.
Login as TestUser3 --> can see only --> TestUser4
Login as TestUser4 --> can see only --> ProgressBar.
```

In other words, when I log in as a user, I am not able to see any of the other users who have registered before me. How do I get to see all the users in my node?

The Realtime dDtabase is like this:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "H4remW9oKDe5iWN74KT5jTHZk1S2" : {
      "email" : "tuser4@gmail.com",
      "mobile" : "1234567890",
      "name" : "TestUser4",
      "online" : "true",
      "photo" : "/v0/b/aivu-a1380.appspot.com/o/images/H4remW9oKDe5iWN74KT5jTHZk1S2.jpg"
    },
    "N0Rx9r71PubzzWkO8YXFABuNZNL2" : {
      "email" : "tuser3@gmail.com",
      "mobile" : "1234567891",
      "name" : "TestUser3",
      "online" : "true",
      "photo" : "/v0/b/aivu-a1380.appspot.com/o/images/N0Rx9r71PubzzWkO8YXFABuNZNL2.jpg"
    },
    "V1AJt2vWOmNKrBzu6EOFdm4aXdI3" : {
      "email" : "tuser1@gmail.com",
      "mobile" : "1234567892",
      "name" : "Sujatha",
      "online" : "true",
      "photo" : "/v0/b/aivu-a1380.appspot.com/o/images/V1AJt2vWOmNKrBzu6EOFdm4aXdI3.jpg"
    },
    "iymUckwHCucx7t4b8mdCkSrqzS22" : {
      "email" : "tuser2@gmail.com",
      "mobile" : "1234567894",
      "name" : "TestUser 2",
      "online" : "true",
      "photo" : "/v0/b/aivu-a1380.appspot.com/o/images/iymUckwHCucx7t4b8mdCkSrqzS22.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate what exactly would like to get, or restrict?

Comment: @AlexMamo. Thank you.  I have added the son to the question.  I would like to get all the users.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which you can solve this. The first approach would be to create a POJO class:

```
class User {
    public String email, mobile, name, online, photo;
}
```

And map each child within your "users" node node into an object of type User. So please try the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
usersRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                Log.d("TAG", user.name);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can get each property separately:

```
usersRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String email = ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                String mobile = ds.child("mobile").getValue(String.class);
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String online = ds.child("online").getValue(String.class);
                String photo = ds.child("photo").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", name);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

In both cases, the result in the logcat will be the name of all users.